# C fopen() unable to open file in /tmp

Tags: c, file-io, io, g++

I am following the basic C programming tutorial on tutorialspoint.com

I have the following program which generates a file in /tmp called test.txt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/tmp/test.text", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "This is testing for fprintf...\n");
    fputs("This is testing for fputs...\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

Then I have a second program which just tries to open that file for reading:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

   FILE *fp = NULL;

   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "r");

   if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("NULL!!!\n");
   }

   printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;

}
```

However, when I try to run the program that opens the file, I get the following output:

```
NULL!!!
No such file or directory
Segmentation fault
```

If I modify the code to point to the same file in my home directory, it works correctly. It seems that, for some reason, I am not able to open files in the /tmp directory (via fopen)... And just to be clear, I am able to change to /tmp and cat the contents of the test.txt file just fine. Permissions look normal on it as well, 664 with my user as the owner and group.

The only other specifics that I can think of that might have to do with my system is that I am on Elementary OS Juno, I am using g++ 7.3.0 (clang also gives the same result), and I have separate encrypted partitions for my OS root and home...

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: you're writing to `"test.text"`, but reading from `"test.txt"` .. note the difference in file extensions.

Comment: Hah! Of course it was something simple like that! Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

This was simply caused by an incorrect file extension, .txt vs.text as pointed out by @yano